# Change shortcut of <Copy "xxx"> in finder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shortcut

I've managed to change shortcut of "Copy" to `^C` for most applications by going to "keyboard->shortcut". But in Finder, the "copy" menu item is dynamic, like `Copy "documents"`, I don't know how to change it.

I am aware of some 3rd party extensions that can do the job, I am just asking if there is any way to achieve this without installing any software.

Comment: what OS X is it ? I do not see the Copy "documents

Comment: Command key has been in use since system 1 so within graphical finder, its really stuck that way. You can still use Ctrl key in terminal tho..

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, trying to individually replace any/all occurrences of the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key with  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  is futile.

You can globally swap the keys in System Prefs > Keyboard > Modifier Keys... but I'm not even sure I'd recommend that.

[image]

Long term, I'd recommend, 
**"Get used to it. Don't fight it."**

Comment: Usually I might say this isn't a solution but really, the command key has been in use on Macintosh since system 1 so why fight it? You still use Ctrl key while using terminal as well